# Python socket garbage response

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, http-headers

**Problem:** I am getting corrupted output when I send the GET request for a webpage.

```
GET http://www.vox.com/a/maps-explain-the-middle-east HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.vox.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
```

output is a bad file containing data like

```
���v�������/�:@�J�|d[��Xt��tF(�p3E%������?�Λ�'��\k��E�7�q����"�®}_sϵ�܏ӛv'�,,ƣ'�=���� K{O>K����l�&�A:ϳ���rѯ��U�4X,f��������_k?=�}9����p��%��d�M���g�Y�([��q��\K�B&)��fǳ
```

But when I send

```
GET http://www.vox.com/a/maps-explain-the-middle-east HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.vox.com\r\n\r\n
```

I got the webpage. I actually added only a few extra headers taken from firefox .
Response headers in both cases are

HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Server: nginx

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Status: 200 OK

X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1

Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

X-Request-Id: f5e482e1dd57f613df9c1b416a65b9b2

X-Runtime: 0.039694

P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa PSAa PSDa CONi OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT CNT STA"

Content-Encoding: gzip

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:39:19 GMT

Age: 0

X-Served-By: cache-iad2129-IAD, cache-lax1430-LAX

X-Cache: MISS, MISS

X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0

X-Timer: S1411555159.330146,VS0,VE108

Vary: Accept-Encoding

X-Cache: MISS from localhost

X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128

Via: 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish, 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)

Connection: close

I don't understand why this is happening Is it some kind of compression.

Edit: But if I use compression how would I recover original data ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I think it is probably due to encoding scheme used.

Because if I don't use 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' I get the correct webpage.

But i don't know how to recover webpage from this encoding